# LWC Upload File/Files to Multiple Contacts

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, fileupload

I have a data table of Contacts on an Account Record Page and I am trying to use the modal component as a file uploader. Basically, you would select a contact or contacts, click the modal button, and then upload file/files to selected contact/contacts.

Is the file uploader component only a one-to-one relationship (i.e. one selected Contact Record Id to one batch of file/batch of file) or can you pass in a set of Contact Record Ids to the file uploader component and upload a file/batch of files to those passed Contact Record Ids?

To handle selecting/deselecting Contacts on the data table, I am using a set since I need a data structure to handle dynamically selecting/deselecting Contacts on that data table and it should be a unique set of Contact Record Ids being sent to the file uploader to upload file/batch of files.

I try and pass the selectedContacts Set into my modal but I an error that the selectedContacts set is undefined when clicking my modal button. Should I use @track on the selectedContacts?

contactListView.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Contacts List View" icon-name="custom:custom63">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <template if:true={contact}>
                <lightning-button label="Upload File(s)" onclick={handlePopup}></lightning-button>
              </template>
              <div class="chart slds-m-around_medium" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
              <section
                id="modal"
                role="dialog"
                tabindex="-1"
                aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01"
                aria-modal="true"
                aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1"
                class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-hide"
              >
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                  <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <button
                      class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse"
                      title="Close"
                    >
                      <svg
                        class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                      >
                        <use
                          xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"
                        ></use>
                      </svg>
                      <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">
                      File Uploader
                    </h2>
                  </header>
                  <div
                    class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium"
                    id="modal-content-id-1"
                  >
                    <div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large" style="width:500px">
                      <lightning-record-edit-form
                        id="recordViewForm"
                        record-id={contact}
                        object-api-name="Contact"
                      >
                        <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="FirstName"> </lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="LastName"> </lightning-input-field>
            
            
            
                        <!-- <lightning-button
                          type="submit"
                          label="Update record"
                          class="slds-m-top_medium"
                          onclick={handleSaveFiles} 
                        >
                        </lightning-button> -->
            
                        
                        <lightning-file-upload
                            label="Attach File(s)"
                            name="fileUploader"
                            accept={acceptedFormats}
                            record-id={contact}
                            onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
                            multiple>
                        </lightning-file-upload>
            
                      </lightning-record-edit-form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <footer class="slds-modal__footer slds-modal__footer_directional">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={handleSkip}>
                      Close
                    </button>
                  </footer>
                </div>
              </section>
              <div
                class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open slds-hide modalBackdrops"
                id="modalBackdrops"
              ></div>
            <!-- <c-file-upload-modal contact={selectedRecord}>
            </c-file-upload-modal> -->

            <template if:true={contact.data}>
                <lightning-datatable
                    key-field="Id"
                    data={contact.data}
                    columns={columns}
                    onrowselection={getSelectedContact}
                    onsave={handleSave}
                    draft-values={draftValues}>
                </lightning-datatable>
            </template>
            <template if:true={contact.error}>
                <!-- handle Apex error -->
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

contactListView.js

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getContacts';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import FIRSTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.FirstName';
import LASTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.LastName';
import TITLE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Title';
import ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Id';


const COLS = [
    { label: 'Id', fieldName: 'Id' },
    { label: 'First Name', fieldName: 'FirstName', editable: true },
    { label: 'Last Name', fieldName: 'LastName', editable: true },
    { label: 'Title', fieldName: 'Title', editable: true},
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone' },
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email' }
];

const columns = [{
    label: 'Title',
    fieldName: 'FileName',
    type: 'url',
    typeAttributes: {
        label: {
            fieldName: 'Title'
        },
        target: '_blank'
    }
}];

export default class contactListView extends LightningElement {

    @track selectedRecord;
    selectedRecords = [];
    // @track selectedRows;
    showLoadingSpinner = false;
    @track fileNames = '';
    @track filesUploaded = [];
    @track data;
    @track cols = columns;
    @api recordId;
    columns = COLS;
    draftValues = [];
    record = {};

    @wire(getContacts, { accId: '$recordId' })
    contact;

    handleSave(event) {

        const fields = {}; 
        fields[ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = event.detail.draftValues[0].Id;
        fields[FIRSTNAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = event.detail.draftValues[0].FirstName;
        fields[LASTNAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = event.detail.draftValues[0].LastName;
        fields[TITLE_FIELD.fieldApiName] = event.detail.draftValues[0].Title;

        const recordInput = {fields};

        updateRecord(recordInput)
        .then(() => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Contact updated',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
            
            return refreshApex(this.contact).then(() => {

                this.draftValues = [];

            });
        }).catch(error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error updating or reloading record',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        });
    }

    getSelectedContact(event){
        const selectedContacts = new Set();
        const selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows;
        for(let i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++){
            // console.log("You selected: " + selectedRows[i].Id)
            selectedContacts.add(selectedRows[i].Id);
        }
        console.log("Selected Contacts: " + selectedContacts);

    }

handlePopup() {
        console.log("Selected Contacts: " + this.selectedContacts);
        // console.log("Selected Contact: " + this.contact.Id)
        this.template.querySelector("section").classList.remove("slds-hide");
        this.template
          .querySelector("div.modalBackdrops")
          .classList.remove("slds-hide");
      }
    
      handleSkip() {
        this.template.querySelector("section").classList.add("slds-hide");
        this.template
          .querySelector("div.modalBackdrops")
          .classList.add("slds-hide");
      }
  
      get acceptedFormats() {
          return ['.pdf', '.png'];
      }
  
      handleUploadFinished(event) {
          // Get the list of uploaded files
          const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;
          alert("No. of files uploaded : " + uploadedFiles.length);
          this.contact = null;
      }
  
      
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, no, but you could upload files to a primary record, and then use the `uploadfinished` event to get a list of files, including the `documentId`, and then create a corresponding list of [ContentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) elements to link the files to any other contacts you'd like as a second step.